# Problem running octave with openmpi in juju

Tags: juju, octave, mpi

I am attempting to use openmpi from octave to start other octave instances on remote machines. When I run the scrip that should start the various processes, it complains about libraries being out of date:

```
Running octave in parallel on /opt/data/octave/test using 24 processors
[pleasant-increase:13959] Warning: could not find environment variable "LD_PRELOAD"
[octave-controller:15259] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_hwloc: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different ver$
[octave-controller:15259] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_auto_detect: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different v$
[octave-controller:15259] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_file: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version $
[octave-controller:15259] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_mmap: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version $
[octave-controller:15259] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_posix: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version$
[octave-controller:15259] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_sysv: perhaps a missing symbol, or compiled for a different version $
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like opal_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during opal_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  opal_shmem_base_select failed
  --> Returned value -1 instead of OPAL_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[octave-controller:15259] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file runtime/orte_init.c at line 79
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed
  --> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

It continues this for the various processes, some of the libraries differing, but always having

```
opal_shmem_base_select failed
...
ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed
```

I have seen comments that say change the compile flags on openmpi and recompile.

A problem is that I am using a local juju repository for provisioning the machines, and I can't figure out where to put the libraries so they get loaded when the provisioning occurs, instead of the version that juju is currently using.  I know the packahes get stored somewhere.  I am not sure if they are on the juju state machine, on the juju server, or if juju acts as it's own apt-get pass-through channel.

any ideas appreciated.

Added 2015.04.28 1723PST-in responce to Robie Basak---------------------------------------------------

Thank you for the bounty, Jorge Castro

My cluster is not connected to the net.  The MaaS controller is connected, for now, but will be disconnected in the future.  When I set up juju, i used a local repository , as in

```
juju sync-tools -e maas --local-dir="~/.juju/sync-tools"
juju bootstrap -e mass --debug --upload-tools=true --metadata-source="~/.juju/sync-tools" --to jujuBS.maas
juju deploy --repository=".juju/charms" local:juju-gui --to 0
juju expose juju-gui
```

I used the same mechanism for the octave and octave-controller charms.  When I look at the unit....log files in /var/log/juju, on one of the nodes, I see many apts getting loaded.  These are stored somewhere, as the node has no access to the net.

Some of these are loaded as the result of the charm loading, so it seems that either MaaS or juju is cognizant of the apt requirements for the charms.  I added some octave packages into the charm and the install, so that octave installed them, and all of a sudden there are required apts that are missing.  These apts are obviously required by the octave package (open-mpi was one, as it turns out).  I downloaded it, added it to the charm and install.  Now the MPI package loads in octave, but gives the status you see above.

Comment: Can you expand on "I am using a local juju repository for provisioning the machines"? Juju itself doesn't have anything to do with apt. If you want to use a different apt source, you can set that up in your charm's `install` hook (easy) or in a more complex way (for example to use an apt repository present in your deployment) using a relation.

Comment: Sorry, formatting does not work in comments, attached to end of post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you're in control; you can do what you like in the charm's `install` hook. The default is to use the main Ubuntu archive with MAAS's squid-deb-proxy acting as a proxy cache; there is no separate mirror or repository active.

> The MaaS controller is connected, for now, but will be disconnected in the future.

I think you're using squid-deb-proxy as supplied by MAAS, which caches packages but nothing more. By default this means that the environment your charm install hook sees is apt configured to use the squid-deb-proxy supplied by MAAS to download packages, but `sources.list` still pointing to the main Ubuntu archive. So your packages are coming from the Ubuntu archive via MAAS as a package cache.

To arrange to use a custom package instead, you want to modify your charms `install` hook to use it by reconfigure apt first. For example you could set up a PPA with your modified package and then arrange for your `install` hook to use it.

You can see a generic example of this in the implementation of the `source` charm configuration option in [mariadb charm's config-changed hook](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~charmers/charms/trusty/mariadb/trunk/view/head:/hooks/config-changed). In the case of a custom charm that you don't need to be generic, you could just add a line like:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:username/octave
```

before you install the package in your `install` hook, or a suitable equivalent if your charm is written in a different language.

If you want to disconnect MAAS machine from Internet access, then you will need to implement your own local apt repository and then either arrange squid-deb-proxy on the MAAS machine to use it in favour of `archive.ubuntu.com` (assuming you have mirrored it), or otherwise arrange for your install hooks to configure apt to use it.

Comment: This answers part of the question, and is good info, @Robie Basak.  I still need to determine how to get octave and open-mpi working together.

Comment: I don't really have any specific knowledge of that, sorry. It might be worth asking that as a separate question independent of MAAS and Juju though. It applies generally, and maybe you'll have a wider audience then. Once you know how to do it outside Juju, you can implement that knowledge inside the Juju charm.